# Delphi debug keep Module Load/Unload bpl,make debug startup very slow

Tags: delphi, debugging

I use Delphi XE, when I start to debug my applicaiton, the Event log shows the debugger keep load & unload bpl, make debug startup very slow?
Does any one know how to solve it? It almost makes me mad!!

I paste some event log below:

```
    Module Load: PIAdditionalX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02790000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIAdditionalX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $05470000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $05270000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxVerticalGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxVerticalGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIDBExpressX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $008A0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIDBExpressX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02720000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02720000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: rtcSDKXE10.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $05270000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $07F50000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $0AC30000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $027D0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02A10000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02610000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02850000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $027D0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02A10000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: frx23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: frx23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: fs23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $021B0000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: fs23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $05270000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxPivotGridRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: cxEditorsRS23.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02590000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: cxEditorsRS23.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Load: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $02990000. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
    Module Unload: PIRuntimeX.bpl. Process IPlatform.exe (4384)
```

Comment: I have the same problem in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE3, it started after updating to Windows Creator Update.

Comment: It seems to be related to loading bpl/dll with image bases that overlap existing loaded bpl's.

Comment: how to resolve this?

Comment: Set your base addresses in such way that bpl's don't overlap. It's still slow and buggy, but it helps.

Comment: This problem should have fixed with Windows 10 v1803.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed with an update of windows, as already mentioned in comments by Chau Chee Yang, but also with an update to the linker in newer versions of Delphi (Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and later). 
For more background information you can read a [blog post](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-june-delphi-packages-creators-update.html) from the Delphi product manager Marco Cantu.